PGN-Extract doesn't work with ELO Ranges
I tried filtering the Lichess Games Database for games in the elo range 600-800. However, when I try a tag-file like this:
WhiteElo <= "800"
WhiteElo >= "600"
BlackElo <= "800"
BlackElo >= "600"

it just ignores the range. When I specify each tag only once, it does work (but obviously with just one limit for that tag). I also tried using the Elo-Tag, but that didn't work either. What could be the problem here?

When you load the code in a debugger , what is it doing?

You mean pgn-extract? What exactly should I be looking for?

Yes, that is a bug. I will have a bug fix release in the near future.

This should now be fixed in version 24-09, released 2nd June 2024.
